# Связать две таблицы с помощью INNER JOIN и получить на выходе третью таблицу

Tags: sql, inner-join

просьба помочь в решении следующей задачи. Есть две таблицы :

- skill_deals - данные по сделкам
- skill_customers_suppliers - справочник продавцов и покупателей одновременно

[image: исходные_таблицы]

В таблице со сделками **skill_deals** есть идентификаторы:

- customer_id — идентификатор покупателя;
- supplier_id — идентификатор продавца

Необходимо с помощью INNER JOIN связать оба идентификатора с таблицей **skill_customers_suppliers**, которая является справочником продавцов и покупателей одновременно (поле-идентификатор customers_suppliers_id).

**Вид результирующей таблицы:**

[image: итоговый_результат]

Написал следующий код :

```
SELECT c.dt,c.customer_name,s.supplier_name

FROM

( select dt,name as customer_name  from skill_deals join skill_customers_suppliers on customer_id =customers_suppliers_id ) c

inner join


( select dt,name as supplier_name  from skill_deals join skill_customers_suppliers on supplier_id =customers_suppliers_id ) s

on c.dt=s.dt
```

но кол-во строк исходной таблицы стало больше (25 вместо 10)

[image: полученный_результат]

Comment: Два поля с независимыми значениями для расшифровки требуют связывания с 2 копиями таблицы-словаря.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM skill_deals t0
JOIN skill_customers_suppliers t1 ON t0.customer_id = t1.customers_suppliers_id
JOIN skill_customers_suppliers t2 ON t0.supplier_id = t2.customers_suppliers_id
```

Comment: Akina, спасибо за пояснение. Ваш код даже более красив с точки зрения написания и логики

Answer (score -1):

Правильный ответ:

```
select dt, c.name,s.name from 
skill_deals d join skill_customers_suppliers c on
d.customer_id=c.customers_suppliers_id join 
skill_customers_suppliers s on 
d.supplier_id=s.customers_suppliers_id
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]